# Running Kotlin from VS Code in UBUNTU gives kotlinc : not found

Tags: java, kotlin, visual-studio-code, ubuntu-20.04

I have installed `kotlin` on ubuntu using `sdkman` command `sdk install kotlin`. `Kotlin` installed and I tested whether `kotlinc` command takes me to the `kotlin interactive shell`. It works and the shell executes the `kotlin` language.

When I tried running `Code Runner` add-on in VS Code to execute a .kt file with a basic `println("Hello World")` function with name main, I get the following error:

```
[Running] cd "/home/user/Dropbox/user/kotlin/" && kotlinc bgn_hello.kt -include-runtime -d bgn_hello.jar && java -jar bgn_hello.jar
/bin/sh: 1: kotlinc: not found

[Done] exited with code=127 in 0.007 seconds
```

Does anyone please have an idea why VS Code is not able to execute the `kotlin` file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add Kotlin to our **PATH** so we can access the compiler without having to write out the full path to our installation. Add the following lines to your `'~/.bashrc'` file.

```
export KOTLIN_HOME=/usr/local/bin/kotlin
export PATH=$PATH:$KOTLIN_HOME/bin
```

Make sure to run `source ~/.bashrc` in order to access the Kotlin compiler in your current terminal session.

Then run `kotlinc -version`, it should return something like `info: kotlinc-jvm 1.5.30 (JRE 11.0.11+9)`

Restart VS Code, the command `kotlinc` should be recognized successfully when using Code Runner.

Comment: It works, thanks. Both given answers are correct.  This one is more OS specific.

Answer (score 6):

This is because your `kotlinc` binaries are not in the `$PATH` environment variable.

I'm on Mac and I added this to my `.bashrc`:

```sh
export PATH="/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc/bin:$PATH"
```

Where `/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc/bin` is where my `kotlinc` binaries exist. Try to see where your kotlin compiler is installed through your IntelliJ IDEA installation and add that line to your `~/.bashrc`.

Note that if you're using other types of shells like Oh-My-Zsh you'd have to modify that file for that shell. In case of Oh-My-Zsh would be `.zshrc`